# Finder not showing DVD/CD drive even when it is checked in the Preferences

Tags: finder, optical-drive

I am playing a DVD so it's definitely "understood" by `macOS` to be present. But not by `Finder` ?

[image]

I tried unchecking and re-checking  the `CDs, DVDs and iPods`: no change.  I have also rebooted the system a few times: the behavior persists.   What can be done here?    I am on `Catalina 10.15.3`

**Update**  The DVD drive is found without any issue on the command line: the following works:

```
diskutil eject /dev/disk2 .
```

Comment: What is your macOS version? What is your Mac model? Does the Terminall command `diskutil list external` display any output?

Comment: The pref you are showing us is for the Desktop… so it should be showing on there. if you want to see it in the sidebar too, you also need to check it in the Sidebar tab.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Yes that's the issue. Not sure how that got "lost". Please make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments, it seems like a simple 'wrong pref'.

The pref in the posted image is for Desktop visibility.
To show in the Finder sidebar, the one required is in the 3rd tab, Sidebar.

[image]